# __xor__ in functools.reduce() causing error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, xor

I'm currently working in python 3 with the Discord API and I want to use a module that was written in python 2. I'm editing some of the code for it to work with python 3. Something I can't figure out is this:

```
odd_xor = reduce(__xor__, bh) >> 16
```

This works in python 2 but doesn't in python 3. The simple fix that I thought would work was:

```
odd_xor = functools.reduce(__xor__, bh) >> 16
```

but this gives me the error:

```
reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value
```

bh is initialized here:

```
# bh stands for binary hand, map to that representation
card_to_binary = HandEvaluator.Six.card_to_binary_lookup
bh = map(card_to_binary, hand)
```

I don't really understand what the code segment is trying to do which is why it is so difficult for me to find a solution to this problem. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

P.S. if there is an easier way to  use python 2 modules with python 3 projects, please enlighten me.

Comment: Can you show us the code before it? Specifically how `bh` is initialized.

Comment: Also, show your imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, `map` returns a lazy iterator (much like a generator), rather than a list the way it did in Python 2. This may be the cause of your issue.

In your code, you do `map(card_to_binary, hand)`. If `hand` gets changed (e.g. emptied) before you use the result, you may not get what you want (e.g. the `map` may end up iterating over nothing).

To make the code work the same as Python 2, you can simply call `list` on the iterator you get from `map`:

```
bh = list(map(card_to_binary, hand))
```

Alternatively, you could change other code that modifies `hand` so that it does something different, perhaps making a new list, copying the list before modifying it, or only modifying `hand` in place after the `reduce` call has been completed.

Answer (score 2):

The said error occurs when the sequence passed as the second argument of `reduce` is empty, which means `bh` is an empty sequence when the error occurs.

Since `bh` is initialized with another sequence, `hand`, you need to find out why `hand` is empty in the first place.